# Unauthorization in flutter even I pass Authorization token

Tags: flutter, dart, unauthorized

I have login screen which will take a few fields and return a response.

`login`

```
  login(String phn, String password) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await getLocation();
    String uri = "$baseUrl/User_Login";
    try {
      http.Response response = await http.post(Uri.parse(uri), headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      }, body: {
        "number": phn,
        "password": password,
        "long": long,
        "lati": lati
      });
      prefs.setString('cookie', response.headers['set-cookie']!);
      return json.decode(response.body);
    } catch (e) {
      return e;
    }
  }
```

and it will return

```
{status: success, Login_Key: f1278a9e15f48866beaeae2503f9b6d4, SESSION_ID: w00mRWDkIpGpz46WrilQ9mhRDyFEon8i0Zuqo89O}
```

and in Homepage I am getting data

```
 getData() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String cookie = prefs.getString('cookie').toString();
    String key = prefs.getString('authKey').toString(); // Login_key
    String session = prefs.getString('sessionKey').toString(); // SESSION_KEY
    String uri = "$baseUrlUser/user_bal";
    var headers = {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $key',
      'Cookie': cookie,
      // 'Token': session,
    };
    print(headers); // shown
    try {
      http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(uri), headers: headers);
      return response.body;
    } catch (e) {
      return e;
    }
  }
```

and even after that `getdata` is returning response to the login page. It is working fine in Postman
this is what `print(Headers)` will do :

```
{Accept: application/json, Authorization: Bearer f1278a9e15f48866beaeae2503f9b6d4, Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6ImZKRnJnZ090a3ZDUWw0UHhrbUpudXc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiNUFWVXNteFRqRE5FWjRRK3luN0xQNWpDa2FtRW5yN2dBRitSeDRaSkZzaGJsN29yZ0swcitSNFR2eWFVM1o3a044UTdFajg0a3NFSzdRbWFuc09qSXl5aFJiOXk4UzR0RTEraVd2THA2YytmRGVxVldla0JFdWhjWGdjVkpaeGwiLCJtYWMiOiI5YzFjZWM2YzBjMzk5ZWUyMjM5MjAzMWZmYTE4ZDY3MTBiMzMwMzU4MzY5MGVhODU5MzllNGIwZDQ1ODRjZTdmIiwidGFnIjoiIn0%3D; expires=Tue, 02-Aug-2022 12:14:43 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; samesite=lax,laravel_session=eyJpdiI6ImhabnFOb0VHbzdCU0ExdzFHSis2UHc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiS0dXdTlZenQxVEdVTTd1NzRXdnE3UjBLSitKY1IrVE5FU2FvSXpxSEx2ZzBxVnJZRWhpbUx0UGZ0bklHVExiK3VDVVlSUFFHd3h6aUZQaWYybUg5RG45b0kzKzJmSEFFTERYajVXWUYycU1nWnVOa25zWnVGU0hhSzVPZXhzakYiLCJtYWMiOiJhN2VkZmUzZmIyMWQ4Zjg5MGMyY2MyMmY5ZTc3ZjhhZDhmMGVmYmJlMTkzMGZjZjBmMmFkMmFkY2NkOTNhN2QyIiwidGFnIjoiIn0%3D; path=/; httponly; samesite=lax}
```

In postman I getting this: [image] which is what i want but in flutter I am getting this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
I/flutter (29556): <html lang="en">
I/flutter (29556): <head>
I/flutter (29556): <meta charset="utf-8">
I/flutter (29556): <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
I/flutter (29556): <meta name="csrf-token" content="OJ0U3KwWLmfE9ym389vebecvFv5rk7u8AZErZEGX" />
I/flutter (29556): <title>Retailer Login | BharatAEPS</title>
I/flutter (29556):
I/flutter (29556): <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,400i,700&display=fallback">
I/flutter (29556):
I/flutter (29556): <link rel="stylesheet" href="../plugins/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css">
I/flutter (29556):
I/flutter (29556): <link rel="stylesheet" href="../plugins/icheck-bootstrap/icheck-bootstrap.min.css">
I/flutter (29556):
I/flutter (29556): <link rel="stylesheet" href="../dist/css/adminlte.min.css">
I/flutter (29556): {Accept: application/json, Authorization: Bearer f1278a9e15f48866beaeae2503f9b6d4, Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IlIzcFF0WXdhM1NCLzYrem9YbXZuR3c9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiVlJIRVBieXhXT0NramwwVVArcEdCd21KNHlPcUdweDRja0lTY1NGekl6aHFnOU1iTGhVWGZ0RHMrWGpSUVF4TlFvdi9DQmUydDJ0d2hCNDB6MllGTE5EMUpoWjFtNWJVdC9LS3p4a0J6QzNVT2Z3TE1zcisrTW1yWDdjdHpRTFYiLCJtYWMiOiI0NmY3YTA1OWIzMGE4MTE4NzZmMDViNjZjMDRjOTM1N2FmZWE1ZGVlZGM0MTg0Yjc0Yzc3ZTIwODNkYTBjMDUyIiwidGFnIjoiIn0%3D; expires=Tue, 02-Aug-2022 12:44:59 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; samesite=lax,laravel_session=eyJpdiI6Ild4TmUxT2tRZXlkbWF1VkRhRmF4Ymc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiWHBYV1QzQTJtM09kVmpqVEg5WUJoT0N5c0w3cy9ZMUMyTmFQV1pKa3hkMGNlTnhTRTBOMjBkeHZlVlUxaEZ4QU5aNnd6R0VpV2lhNUhCOHBibExOWU9NeWZaMzBjTzVlMURyTG9QeUtldTc0QWRqd0Y3RTQrbG1obFZiaFBWU0giLCJtYWMiOiJmMmRmZDFiYzc1NjU4MDQ2NTI5ZTYxM2NlZDdlYzUxMzQ4NmY5MjQ2ZDc0M2Q5ODZjMTBjNzU1YWM5MzQ1ZDE0IiwidGFnIjoiIn0%3D; path=/; httponly; samesite=lax}
E/flutter (29556): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: This widget has been unmounted, so the State no longer has a context (and should be considered defunct).
I/flutter (29556): <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://aeps.bharataeps.com/css/loader/loader.css">
I/flutter (29556): <style type="text/css">
I/flutter (29556):     .bgc{
I/flutter (29556): background: #FC466B;  /* fallback for old browsers */
I/flutter (29556): background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #3F5EFB, #FC466B);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
I/flutter (29556): background: linear-gradient(to right, #3F5EFB, #FC466B); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
2
I/flutter (29556):
I/flutter (29556):     }
I/flutter (29556):     .hide{
```

Comment: Can you share what you get from your header

Comment: try {
      http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(uri), headers: headers);
      return response.body;
    } catch (e) {
    print(e); // add this and update your question
      return e;
    }
  }

Comment: Explain more what is the problem. You description "and even after that getdata is returning response to the login page." is not clear

Comment: Check my updated answer

Comment: Did the url correction work ? @SandeepSharma

Answer (score 1):

To debug API response, you first need to know what is returned by your server.

### Step 1

Print the error with the lined added below

```
try {
      http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(uri), headers: headers);
      return response.body;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e); // add this and update your question
      return e;
    }
  }
```

### Step 2

Check the URL     `String uri = "$baseUrlUser/user_bal";`, inside your Postman, the correct URL is `User_Bal` (Case sensitive maybe)

Answer (score 0):

In your header you are getting a `Cookie` not a `set-cookie` so your code should be.

```
prefs.setString('cookie', response.headers['Cookie']!);
```

Comment: I am getting error `Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: Class '_CastError' has no instance method '[]'`